# while loop doesnt respond until 3rd input and doesnt say "tvoj broj je tacan" python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

heres the code this code has print commands in the serbian languange
when launching the code the first 3 inputs just respond with the question "izaberi broj izmedju 0 do 100" then after the three inputs it finally starts working

```py
import random
pitanje = int(input("izaberi broj od 0 do 100"))
broj = int(random.randint(0, 100))
while(pitanje != broj):
    pitanje = int(input("izaberi broj od 0 do 100"))
    broj = int(random.randint(0, 100))
    if pitanje > broj:
        print("tvoj broj je prevelik")
    elif pitanje < broj:
        print("tvoj broj je premali")
    elif pitanje == broj:
        print("tvoj broj je tacan")
```

Comment: "then after the three inputs it finally starts working" What do you mean by this? If you expect to get one of the ``print`` "replies", those are working for the second input already. The first is immediately discarded in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, because you ask the question twice before you do any checking.  Just make this an "infinite" loop, and "break" when you get a match:

```
import random
broj = int(random.randint(0, 100))
while True:
    pitanje = int(input("izaberi broj od 0 do 100"))
    if pitanje > broj:
        print("tvoj broj je prevelik")
    elif pitanje < broj:
        print("tvoj broj je premali")
    else:
        print("tvoj broj je tacan")
        break
```